# How to get 'IOPlatformUUID' on OS X 10.4?

Tags: macos, uuid

I need to get UUID value on 10.4 but the command seems not to be supported here.

```
ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { split($0, line, "\""); printf("%s\n", line[4]); }'
```

Above command is working fine on 10.5. Is this not supported on 10.4?

Also I am trying to fetch UUID using below code on 10.4, which is also not working:

```
void vlm_getSystemUUID_MAC(char * uuid, int bufSize)
{
    io_registry_entry_t ioRegistryRoot = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/");
    CFStringRef uuidCf = (CFStringRef) IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(ioRegistryRoot, CFSTR(kIOPlatformUUIDKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    IOObjectRelease(ioRegistryRoot);
    CFStringGetCString(uuidCf, uuid, bufSize, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
    CFRelease(uuidCf);
}
```

And the above code executes well on 10.5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `IOPlatformUUID` was first added to Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard, and wasn't available in previous versions (someone please correct me if I'm wrong). [This blog post](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=leopard_byhost_changes) hints that this change was added in 10.5.

To ID a Mac running Mac OS X 10.4 and earlier, you'll have to use either the `IOPlatformSerialNumber` and/or built-in MAC address. See this for details and caveats: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn1103/_index.html